# How to reuse MongoDB connection in Go

Tags: database, mongodb, go, database-connection

I would like to connect my server that was written in Go with a MongoDB but I'm not sure how to do it in an efficient way. A couple of examples I found implemented it like shown below.

**libs/mongodb/client.go**

```golang
package mongodb

import (
    "context"
    "log"
    "project/keys"

    "go.mongodb.org/mongo-driver/mongo"
    "go.mongodb.org/mongo-driver/mongo/options"
)

func GetClient() *mongo.Database {
    client, err := mongo.Connect(
        context.Background(),
        options.Client().ApplyURI(keys.GetKeys().MONGO_URI),
    )

    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    return client.Database(keys.GetKeys().MONGO_DB_NAME)
}
```

**services/user/findOne.go**

```golang
package userservices

import (
    "context"
    "log"
    "project/libs/mongodb"
    "project/models"

    "go.mongodb.org/mongo-driver/bson"
)

func FindOne(filter bson.M) (models.User, error) {
    var user models.User

    collection := mongodb.GetClient().Collection("users")
    result := collection.FindOne(context.TODO(), filter)

    if result.Err() != nil {
        return user, result.Err()
    }

    if err := result.Decode(&user); err != nil {
        log.Println("Failed to decode user with error:", err)
        return user, err
    }

    return user, nil
}
```

The `GetClient` function returns a database instance that is then used throughout the app. This seems to work, but I'm wondering if this really is best practice as it seems to create a new connection every time a new client is requested as shown in the second code snippet or is that assumption incorrect? I also thought about converting `GetClient` to a singleton, that always returns the same database instance but how would a lost connection be handled in that case? Thank you

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I do it this way. Do it once at the service start and then pass the MongoDatastore object around to orchestrator, service layers and repository layers. I am using the "github.com/mongodb/mongo-go-driver/mongo" driver for mongo. I think it internally monitors and recycles idle connections. Hence, we don't have to bother about broken connections as long as reference to the mongo.Client object is not lost.

```
const CONNECTED = "Successfully connected to database: %v"

type MongoDatastore struct {
    db      *mongo.Database
    Session *mongo.Client
    logger  *logrus.Logger
}

func NewDatastore(config config.GeneralConfig, logger *logrus.Logger) *MongoDatastore {

    var mongoDataStore *MongoDatastore
    db, session := connect(config, logger)
    if db != nil && session != nil {

        // log statements here as well

        mongoDataStore = new(MongoDatastore)
        mongoDataStore.db = db
        mongoDataStore.logger = logger
        mongoDataStore.Session = session
        return mongoDataStore
    }

    logger.Fatalf("Failed to connect to database: %v", config.DatabaseName)

    return nil
}

func connect(generalConfig config.GeneralConfig, logger *logrus.Logger) (a *mongo.Database, b *mongo.Client) {
    var connectOnce sync.Once
    var db *mongo.Database
    var session *mongo.Client
    connectOnce.Do(func() {
        db, session = connectToMongo(generalConfig, logger)
    })

    return db, session
}

func connectToMongo(generalConfig config.GeneralConfig, logger *logrus.Logger) (a *mongo.Database, b *mongo.Client) {

    var err error
    session, err := mongo.NewClient(generalConfig.DatabaseHost)
    if err != nil {
        logger.Fatal(err)
    }
    session.Connect(context.TODO())
    if err != nil {
        logger.Fatal(err)
    }

    var DB = session.Database(generalConfig.DatabaseName)
    logger.Info(CONNECTED, generalConfig.DatabaseName)

    return DB, session
}
```

You may now create your repository as below:-

```
type TestRepository interface{
    Find(ctx context.Context, filters interface{}) []Document, error
}

type testRepository struct {
    store      *datastore.MongoDatastore
}

func (r *testRepository) Find(ctx context.Context , filters interface{}) []Document, error{
    cur, err := r.store.GetCollection("some_collection_name").Find(ctx, filters)
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }
    defer cur.Close(ctx)
    var result = make([]models.Document, 0)
    for cur.Next(ctx) {
        var currDoc models.Document
        err := cur.Decode(&currDoc)
        if err != nil {
            //log here
            continue
        }
        result = append(result, currDoc)
    }
    return result, err
}
```

Comment: I'm coming from Ruby and I'm a bit shocked by the amount of ugly code that is needed to handle a DB connection. Is there really no better way to do it? Maybe a library which is abstracting all this ugly details away?

Answer (score 1):

I solved it doing this

```
var CNX = Connection()
func Connection() *mongo.Client {
    // Set client options
    clientOptions := options.Client().ApplyURI("mongodb://localhost:27017")

    // Connect to MongoDB
    client, err := mongo.Connect(context.TODO(), clientOptions)

    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    // Check the connection
    err = client.Ping(context.TODO(), nil)

    if err != nil {
    log.Fatal(err)
    }

    fmt.Println("Connected to MongoDB!")

    return client
  }

//calll connection
 func main() {
      collection := db.CNX.Database("tasks").Collection("task")
 }

output "Connected to MongoDB!"
```

Comment: And how exactly can you export that CNX to another package?

Comment: Every variable, function, interface or struct that starts with a capital is deemed public and is available to other packages. You just need to use it with the package name in front. For instance, if we assume the above code is in a package `db`, you can access it as `db.CNX`

Comment: @Shadoweb Hello, you just import this package or function example,       
    import myConnection "yourDbConnectionPath"

    the i used like this

    collection := myConnection.CNX.Database("tasks").Collection("task")

Comment: I did the same but as I tring to insert smt I get - exit status 1.
But if I do this in the same funciton where client is created it works fine.

Answer (score 0):

What I have done is this way:

I have a **app.go** file to make a **mongoDB connection** inside **config** folder that I have created

```
func Connection() *mongo.Client {
if err := godotenv.Load(); err != nil {
    log.Println("No .env file found")
}
uri := os.Getenv("MONGODB_URI")
if uri == "" {
    log.Fatal("You must set your 'MONGODB_URI' environmental variable. See\n\t https://www.mongodb.com/docs/drivers/go/current/usage-examples/#environment-variable")
}
// Set client options
clientOptions := options.Client().ApplyURI(uri)

// Connect to MongoDB
client, err := mongo.Connect(context.TODO(), clientOptions)

if err != nil {
    log.Fatal(err)
}

// Check the connection
err = client.Ping(context.TODO(), nil)

if err != nil {
    log.Fatal(err)
}

fmt.Println("Connected to MongoDB!")

return client
}
```

I have called this function in another file called **employee.go** which resides in **model folder**

```
var CNX = config.Connection()

func (e *Employee) CreateEmployeeDetails() *Employee {
    coll := CNX.Database("employee").Collection("detail")
    fmt.Println(coll)
    result, err := coll.InsertOne(context.TODO(), e)
    fmt.Printf("Inserted document with _id: %v\n", result.InsertedID)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    return e
}
```