# How to connect to MongoDB in a separate function?

Tags: database, mongodb, go

In this code, I am connecting the MongoDB database with golang and inserting data in it. I want to separate the `Connection()` function from `Insertdata()` function (from other functions also that I made like `Finddata()`, `Deletedata()`, etc).

But when I try to separate it, the `client` variable from `Connection()` function gives me a message that `it is declared but not used` and the `client` variable from `Insertdata()` gives me a message that `it is undeclared`. How to handle this?

```
func Connection() {
    // Set client options
    clientOptions := options.Client().ApplyURI("mongodb://localhost:27017")

    // Connect to MongoDB
    client, err := mongo.Connect(context.TODO(), clientOptions)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
}
func Insertdata(inputData interface{}) {
    Connection()
    err, collection := client.Database("PMS").Collection("dataStored")
    collection.InsertOne(context.TODO(), inputData)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
}
```

Comment: Do not connect before each operation. Connecting may be a very lengthy task. Connect once, on app startup, and reuse the `client` whenever / wherever needed. It is safe for concurrent use.

Comment: How can I connect once if the client is giving me the message declared and undeclared.

Comment: I would likely create some abstraction around the database (`type DB struct { /*...*/ }`), which would hold a `*mongo.Client` (or an interface satisfied by the latter). I would then declare `Insertdata` as a method on `*DB`. That way, I would only connect once when instantiating a `DB`, and I would be able to use (and re-use) that client from the method through its receiver.

Answer (score 1):

Please note that the `Connection()` function in your code does not return the `client` instance. You would need to return `client` in order to use it in your other `Insertdata` function.

Additionally, I suggest to read through the [Usage section on the mongo-go-driver Github page](https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-go-driver#usage). A good example of how to handle MongoDB connections in Go can be also found in [How to reuse MongoDB connection in Go](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58365838/how-to-reuse-mongodb-connection-in-go).

Answer (score 1):

In Go, we typically store dependencies in struct type fields. Define some abstraction around the database that will hold a `*mongo.Client` (or an interface satisfied by that type):

```golang
type DB struct {
  client *mongo.Client
}
```

Instantiate the client once in a factory function for your `DB` type:

```golang
func NewDB(ctx context.Context, uri string) (*DB, error) {
    clientOptions := options.Client().ApplyURI(uri)
    client, err := mongo.Connect(ctx, clientOptions)
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }
    db := DB {
        client: client,
    }
    return &db, nil
}
```

Then declare `Insertdata` as a *method* (not a *function*) on `*DB`.  That way, you'll be able to use (and re-use) the client within that method through its receiver.

```golang
func (db *DB) Insertdata(ctx context.Context, inputData interface{}) error {
    collection := db.client.Database("PMS").Collection("dataStored")
    _, err := collection.InsertOne(ctx, inputData)
    return err
}
```

Also:

- Don't hardcode `context.TODO()` in your production code. Add a `context.Context` parameter to make the relevant functions and methods cancellable from higher up the call stack.
- Don't ignore errors. If you can't handle them within a function or method, return them to the caller.